# Export data to Excel in Laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to make export data into excel in my project, i have made it, but after I check the results, the results  doesnt like what I want. here I would like to make a result there is a title table.

This code my controller:

```
public function getExport(){
        Excel::create('Export data', function($excel) {

        $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) {

            $products=DB::table('log_patrols')
            ->join("cms_companies","cms_companies.id","=","log_patrols.id_cms_companies")
            ->join("securities","securities.id","=","log_patrols.id_securities")
            ->select("log_patrols.*","cms_companies.name as nama_companies","securities.name as nama_security")
            ->get();
                foreach($products as $product) {
                 $data[] = array(
                    $product->date_start,
                    $product->date_end,
                    $product->condition_status,
                    $product->nama_security,
                    $product->nama_companies,
                );
            }
            $sheet->fromArray($data);
        });
    })->export('xls');
    }
```

this my problem result :
[image: result]

and it should be :

[image: should]

my problem is how to change the number into text what i want in the header table.

what improvements do i have to make to the code to achieve my goal?

**NB** : i use maatwebsite/excel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the official [docs](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export):

> By default the export will use the keys of your array (or model
>   attribute names) as first row (header column). To change this
>   behaviour you can edit the default config setting
>   (excel::export.generate_heading_by_indices) or **pass false as 5th**
>   parameter:

**Change:**

`$sheet->fromArray($data);` to `$sheet->fromArray($data, null, 'A1', false, false);`

> how to change the number into text what i want in the header table.

Then you can define your own heading and prepend it to the first row of the sheet.

```
$headings = array('date start', 'date end', 'status condition', 'security', 'company');

$sheet->prependRow(1, $headings);
```

That should make it work.

Comment: ahh oke, that help me. maybe can i make style in thats result like i want to make border table ?

Comment: For border styling, please refer to the [sheet styling guide](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export#sheet-styling) and the [reference guide](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/reference-guide#borders) to see the available border styles.

Comment: Also, if this solved your question, can you mark this as the answer..thanks.:)

Comment: only first cell works but after that give me number ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller

```
$data=Insertion::get()->toArray();
    return Excel::create('yourfilename', function($excel) use ($data) {
        $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data)
        {
            $sheet->cell('A1:C1',function($cell)
            {
                $cell->setAlignment('center');
                $cell->setFontWeight('bold');
            });

            $sheet->cell('A:C',function($cell)
            {
                $cell->setAlignment('center');
            });

            $sheet->cell('A1', function($cell) 
            {
                $cell->setValue('S.No');  

            });
            $sheet->cell('B1', function($cell) 
            {
                $cell->setValue('Name'); 
            });
            $sheet->cell('C1', function($cell) 
            {
                $cell->setValue('Father Name');    
            });
            if (!empty($data)) {
                $sno=1;
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) 
                {
                    $i= $key+2;
                    $sheet->cell('A'.$i, $sno); 
                    $sheet->cell('B'.$i, $value['name']); 
                    $sheet->cell('C'.$i, $value['fathername']);  
                    $sno++;
                }
            }
        });
    })->download(xlsx);
```